# Minimal packages required for a new Angular 2.0.0-rc.5 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, package.json

I am working on my second project that involves Angular 2. After warming up with the first Angular 2 project, while making the jump from Angular 1.5, I got really interested on how to trim down the packages. I'd like to know what can I eliminate from the `package.json` file without loosing core functionality. What does each package contribute and what should I spare?

Here's what I understand so far:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server", // I use Webstorm, Visual Studio or Xampp
    "postinstall": "typings install", // ???
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w", // Maybe I will keep
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5", // ng-if, ng-for seem to reside in here
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5", // renders the templates
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5", // :)
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0", // I could manage without, I use custom css
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5", // Need it
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5", // ???
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5", // ???
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1", // Need it
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2", // Nope
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5", // Nope
    "systemjs": "0.19.27", // importing modules
    "core-js": "^2.4.0", // Some polyfills, Does Chrome 52.0 needs it?
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3", // Decorators ??
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6", // depdency for EventEmitter 
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12", // data bindings don't work wihtout
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15", // ???
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6" // No need, I do all my css hand forged to perfection.
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0", // Nope
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0", // Nope
    "typescript": "^1.8.10", // Nope ? I learned that Webstorm can do this job
    "typings":"^1.0.4" // Nope ?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree.

As discussed in [the official blog post accompanying the RC5 release](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html)

> Roughly 60% of Angular’s code size is the compiler [...] so enabling AoT compilation means you don’t have to ship that code to your users

If minimizing bytes over the wire is your concern, I'd suggest learning how to leverage this by incorporating AoT compilation into your build process (which, with respect to your question, would allow you to remove the `compiler` and `platform-browser-dynamic` modules from your production bundle)

It's also worth noting that trimming the size of these modules in prep for final release [is one of the major focuses for RC6](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1rC5dz7AkCZP813daT_bccbS-20OLmXgBVi50CSKx148/pub), so IMHO doing what you're doing with RC5 is mostly a waste of time.